# jQuery predicate selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, selector

I'm not sure my jQuery selector is correct: $("div[class^='reviewdiv']")

```js
var dispContent = $("div[class^='reviewdiv']");
console.log(dispContent);
```

```html
    <div class='reviewdiv_1'>
        <img class='img_review' src='../images/man_1.png'> 
    </div>            
    <div class='reviewdiv_2'>
        <img class='img_review' src='../images/man_2.png'> 
    </div>            
    <div class='reviewdiv_3'>
        <img class='img_review' src='../images/man_3.png'> 
    </div>
```

Console is showing the following, which I assume is wrong, because I cannot run .each method though this array:

[div.reviewdiv_1, div.reviewdiv_2, div.reviewdiv_3, prevObject: n.fn.init[1], context: document, selector: "div[class^='reviewdiv']"]

Comment: This error is because jquery is not included.
"Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. nothing wrong with your code, except that you should perhaps remove the single quotes in the class selector. but it works even if you keep the quotes.

```
$("div[class^=reviewdiv]").each(function(index,element){
         console.log(index,element);
});
```

Just note that the element is unwrapped, so you need to do $(element) to get the JQuery element for it.

Comment: now it works, the problem was with $(this) in the function